Why does my C# app crashes without any error when debugger is attached?
I have a .Net Core (ver 8.0) multiproject solution which uses a native library on Linux (.so).
When I start the project with debugger on, the program exits with code 0 and without any messages when hitting the line which loads the library.
Without the debugger, it runs without issues.
How can I get debugging to work?

You have tried catching potential exceptions?

Yes, nothing is thrown.

What I just noticed: if not stepping over the line with the native load (but instead setting a breakpoint some lines down), the program will execute a few lines more until crashing.
